# How to bechmark a method in Octave?

Tags: performance, matlab, octave

Matlab has [timeit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) method which is helpful to compare the performance of an implementation with another. I couldn't find something similar in octave. I wrote this benchmark method with runs a function f N times and then returns the total time taken. Is this a reasonable way to compare different implementations or am I missing something critical like "warmup"?

```matlab
function elapsed_time_in_seconds = benchmark(f, N)
  % benchmark runs the function 'f' N times and returns the elapsed time in seconds.

  timeid = tic;
  for i=1:N
    output = f();
  end
  elapsed_time_in_seconds = toc(timeid);
end
```

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider is realtime vs cputime. As per [the octave manual](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Timing-Utilities.html#XREFtic): "If you are more interested in the CPU time that your process used, you should use the cputime function instead. The tic and toc functions report the actual wall clock time that elapsed between the calls. This may include time spent processing other jobs or doing nothing at all."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MATLAB's `timeit` does the following (you can read the whole function, it's an M-file):

1. Obtain a rough estimate `t_rough` of the time for calling the function `f`.
2. Use the estimate to determine `N` such that `N*t_rough` is about 0.001 s.
3. Determine `M` such that `M*N*t_rough` is no more than 15 s, but `M` must be between 3 and 11.
4. Loop `M` times:
5. Call `f()` `N` times and record the total time.
6. Determine the median of the `M` times, divided by `N`.

The purpose of the two loops, `M` and `N`, is as follows: Calling `f()` `N` times ensures that the time measured by `tic`/`toc` is sufficiently large to be reliable, this loop avoids attempting to time something that is so short that it cannot be timed. Repeating the measurement `M` times and keeping the median attempts to make the measurement robust against delays caused by other stuff happening on your system, which can artificially inflate the recorded time.

The function subtracts the overhead of calling a function through its handle (determined experimentally by timing the call of an empty function), as well as the `tic`/`toc` call time (also determined experimentally). It does not subtract the cost of the inner loop, presumably because in MATLAB it is optimized by the JIT and its cost is negligible.

There are some further refinements. The function that determines `t_rough` first warms up `tic` and `toc` by calling each one twice, then it uses a `while` loop to ensure it calls `f()` for at least 0.001 s. But in this loop, if the first iteration takes at least 3 s, it just takes that time as the rough estimate. If the first iteration takes less time, the first time count is discarded (warmup), and then uses the median of all the subsequent calls as the rough estimate of the time.

There's also a lot of effort put into calling the function `f()` with the right number of output arguments.

The code has a lot of comments explaining the reason behind all these steps, it is worth reading.

---

As a minimum, I would augment your benchmark function as follows:

```matlab
function elapsed_time_in_seconds = benchmark(f, N, M)
  % benchmark runs the function 'f' N*M times and returns the elapsed time in seconds.

  tic; [~] = toc; tic; [~] = toc; % warmup
  output = f(); % warmup

  t = zeros(M, 1);
  for k=1:M
    timeid = tic;
    for i=1:N
      output = f();
    end
    t(k) = toc(timeid) / N;
  end
  elapsed_time_in_seconds = median(t);
end
```

If you use the function to directly compare various alternatives, keeping `N` and `M` constant, then the overheads of `tic`, `toc`, function calls and loops is irrelevant.

This function does assume that `f` has one output argument, which is not necessarily the case. You could just call `f()` instead of `output = f()`, which will work for functions with or without output arguments. But if the function needs to have a certain number of outputs to work correctly, or to trigger computations that you want to time, then you'd have to adjust the function to call it with the right number of output arguments.

You could come up with some heuristic to determine `M` from `N`, which would make it a little easier to use this function.

Comment: Where I can find the code for MATLAB's timeit?

Comment: @Turbo: Type `edit timeit` at the MATLAB prompt.

Comment: @Turbo: It used to be on the FileExchange, but I guessed they pulled it from there once it was added to core MATLAB. This is the original blog post where author Steve Eddins discusses  this function: https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/29/timing-code-in-matlab/?s_tid=srchtitle -- he had several more blog posts talking about upgrades to it.

Comment: I am able to see the source code by running `edit timeit` at [matlab online](https://matlab.mathworks.com/).

Comment: Lots of useful information on how `timeit` works!

Comment: I don't think octave uses JIT in the same way (at least for now). Is a 'warmup' really necessary in Octave?

Comment: @Tasos, warmup was useful in MATLAB before the JIT was introduced. MATLAB has always read in and parsed each function only once (until `clear all`). I assume Octave does the same thing, because it makes sense. But I don't know.

Comment: @Tasos: Indeed, this is true for Octave as well. For example run `tic; cos(2); toc` a few times, starting with a fresh session. The first time it takes ~10x as long as the other times, even though all three are built-in methods.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ah yes [of course](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Function-Files.html#Function-Files). Good catch.